# How to add specific recipient in jenkins job email loop when the job is triggered manually?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a situation like want to send e-mail to specific people when that job is manually triggered. If the same job is triggered automatically I just want to include few more people into that loop. Is it possible without creating another duplicate job for this task? Because when our dev., team executing job, the email is triggered to manager which they're not want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a conditional (build or post-build) step where you use the build cause as discriminator in order to send the e-mail(s).

You will need the 'conditional build step' plug-in for this to work. See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin

Comment: I just missed to inform a thing. Is it possible to change the recipient by the user? I have some tempuser, and admin users. If I triggered job through tempuser I need different email recipient. and the same for admin user.

Comment: Just use different conditions for different send lists? However I've no recent experience with the e-mail sending plug-in. But maybe https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin is of help, too?

Answer (score 0):

In email setting Add trigger and use

> Send To Requester

- If this is checked, an email will be sent user who triggers the build (if triggered by a user manually).

You can specify the recipient list for manual trigger, however you can't define different recipient list for different users who trigger the build.